# Why is this destructor called 7 times?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, destructor, std-function

Any idea why this is happening? I am compiling Visual Studio 19

```
#include <functional>

struct FOO
{
    ~FOO() {
        std::cout << "Destructor called\n";
    }
    void operator()() {}
};
void main()
{
    FOO* foo = new FOO;
    FOO* foo2 = new FOO;
    std::function<void(void)> func = *foo; // Destructor called here, 
}
```

It calls once during the copy func = *foo; and then when the program exits. I understand that. However:

```
#include <functional>

struct FOO
{
    
    ~FOO() {
        
        
        std::cout << "Destructor called\n";

    }
    void operator()() {}
};
void main()
{
    FOO* foo = new FOO;
    FOO* foo2 = new FOO;
    std::function<void(void)> func = *foo; // Destructor called here
    
    int breakPoint = 0;

    func = *foo2; // Destructor called 5 times here!!!
    
    breakPoint = 3;

    
}
```

Called 5 times at func = *foo2; plus one from before, and one on program exit, that's 7 in total. Anybody know where all these destructor calls are coming from? I expected a maybe a temporary created during the copy, that's two copies, and then one when the program exits, that's 3. But 7? And it's strange it's doing it now even in Release mode, the destructor is called 7 times even in Release mode.

Edit: For anyone who doesn't believe I'm getting 7 destructor calls, this is what I run, on Visual Studio 19, both debug, and funny enough Release:

```
#include <functional>

struct FOO
{
    static inline int count = 0;
    ~FOO() {
        count++;
        std::cout << "Destructor called " << count << " times\n";
    }
    void operator()() {}
};
int main()
{
    FOO* foo = new FOO;
    FOO* foo2 = new FOO;
    std::function<void(void)> func = *foo; // Destructor called here


    func = *foo2; // Destructor called 5 times here!!!


    std::cout << "FOO destructor called " << FOO::count << " times, with another call to come when program exits\n";
}

//Destructor called 1 times
//Destructor called 2 times
//Destructor called 3 times
//Destructor called 4 times
//Destructor called 5 times
//Destructor called 6 times
//FOO destructor called 6 times, with another call to come when program exits
//Destructor called 7 times
```

Comment: `func` stores an instance of  `FOO`.

Comment: gcc and clang only print 4 times. Also, `main` returns `int`.

Comment: @cigien It should be one each for the copies, that's two, and then one on exit, no?

Comment: @Zebrafish Overload all possible compiler generated constructor variants and track these (using `std::cout`), and then count again.

Comment: @brc-dd One for foo, one for foo2, one for the std::function that gets destroyed on program exit, that's 3 calls. There are two copies, if the destructor gets called on the copies that would be 5.

Comment: What @πάνταῥεῖ suggested: https://godbolt.org/z/PWfMab

Comment: There may be [better dupes](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE833DE833&sxsrf=ALeKk016sNHUk7TJYWL7BSxfUNzBFtz3lg%3A1603611384994&ei=-CqVX634O8rhkgX9nbKIDQ&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22c%2B%2B%22+more+destructor+calls+than+constructor&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22c%2B%2B%22+more+destructor+calls+than+constructor&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECAAQR1DoziFYq9QiYJrjImgAcAJ4AoABmQmIAeRLkgEQNC4yMi4zLjMuMC40LjEuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwit1Nb3nc_sAhXKsKQKHf2ODNEQ4dUDCA0&uact=5). I didn't check in depth.

Comment: @cigien The move after copy _is_ a bit surprising.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah, I wasn't expecting that. I think the dupe does answer the question though, so unless OP disagrees, I think it's ok.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I do want to know what's going on there though :p

Comment: @cigien Yeah, me too :-)  I can't find the explanation for it on cppreference though. Perhaps one has to look in the standard.

Comment: @TedLyngmo First overload essentially calls [swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator%3D). That's probably it.

Comment: I don't think the other answer addresses my question. With one copy I have two destructor calls, and doing another copy calls the destructor another 5 times.

Comment: @cigien I noticed that. The assignment is also `function(std::forward<F>(f)).swap(*this)`

Comment: @Zebrafish I don't see 7 dtors. In the example I made, there are only 4.

Comment: Ok, I don't want to say I don't believe you, but are you sure you're getting 7 destructor calls? I haven't run this with VS myself.

Comment: @cigien Yes, I edited the question to put the exact code. Godbolt only calls 4 times, but I don't understand that, the destructor for the two pointers aren't called, so there's one for a temporary on the first copy, another on the second copy, and then one when std::function is destroyed on exit, that's 3.

Comment: Ok, but if this is only happening on your machine, it's not exactly reproducible. Can you try an online compiler that has VS, and add a link to that?

Comment: I just fired up Visual Studio and can confirm the 7 dtors being called in the code in the question. I'd say it's something odd, perhaps even a bug, in MSVC. If you add a user defined copy constructor you'll only get the 4 dtors called: `FOO() = default; FOO(const FOO&) {}`

Comment: @TedLyngmo So on the second copy it calls the destructor twice, as opposed to once on the first copy? Hmm, I'm wondering why it calls the copy constructor and then the move constructor. Even in release build mode this happens?

Comment: It seems to be in the assignment where it does something wierd. The dtor is called 5 times in that call. Yes, it seems odd that it copies then moves but @cigien and I described the probable cause for that further up in the comments.

Comment: It can be made even worse - If you make `foo` and `foo2` automatic variables, not even the user defined copy constructor will help. Try [this](https://godbolt.org/z/rcGvYT) in Visual Studio. It'll show you that when doing the assignment, it does one copy and 4(!!!) moves.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah 4 moves I don't get this. Usually I'd expect this in debug mode and then all of these constructor calls to disappear in Release mode. Disappointing.

Comment: @Zebrafish It's indeed odd. The assignment operators look like `function& operator=(function&& _Right) noexcept /* strengthened */ {
        if (this != _STD addressof(_Right)) {
            this->_Tidy();
            this->_Reset_move(_STD move(_Right));
        }
        return *this;
    }`  ...

Comment: ... and `#if _USE_FUNCTION_INT_0_SFINAE
    template <class _Fx, typename _Mybase::template _Enable_if_callable_t<decay_t<_Fx>&, function> = 0>
#else // ^^^ _USE_FUNCTION_INT_0_SFINAE // !_USE_FUNCTION_INT_0_SFINAE vvv
    template <class _Fx, class = typename _Mybase::template _Enable_if_callable_t<decay_t<_Fx>&, function>>
#endif // _USE_FUNCTION_INT_0_SFINAE
    function& operator=(_Fx&& _Func) {
        function(_STD forward<_Fx>(_Func)).swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Hmm, interesting. In that case, the dupe doesn't address the question. I'll reopen.

Comment: I reopened the question, and added relevant tags.

Comment: @cigien Yes, that's probably a good idea. Zebrafish: By looking at the MSVC code someone can probably explain what's happening, but _why_ it's implemented like this in MSVC may be hard to explain.

Comment: Am I correct to assume you're using C++17 or later?

Comment: @Chipster Yes, either c++17 or std::c++ latest

Comment: I tend to think it is the problem of VS itself, I suggest that you could ask this question [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

Comment: I'm not sure if you can see my feedback-report to MS, but I put it up there anyway so you can vote on it if you wish. Title if you need to search for it: "_std::function makes a lot of moves upon assignment_". Link: https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/std::function-makes-a-lot-of-moves-upon-/1249768